# Is there a verb that concisely describes this facial expression?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What's a word that describes that face you make when you're worried or appealing to someone, where the insides of your eyebrows curve up towards your hairline? The sort of face that Puss makes in the *Shrek* films when he's begging for something.

Is there a one-word way of communicating that on the page? A "she *X*ed at him" sort of thing, like *frown* or *scowl.* (Of course, *frown* and *scowl* mean the eyebrows go down in the middle. What's the opposite movement called?)

Comment: 'She furrowed her brow' - can someone make an answer out of this? (With links and explanation and stuff)

Comment: You mean like Christine Blasey Ford peering over the top of her glasses at the recent Senate hearing? I've heard / seen a number of people refer to that as ***[cutesying](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cutesying%22) it** [up]* - "verbifying" adjectival ***cutesy*** (an unmistakably pejorative variant of ***cute***).

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a verb, but I think “making puppy eyes” or “doing puppy eyes” would describe the facial expression you’re referring to.

Answer (score -2):

You are asking for a **verb** to concisely relate a complex **set of facial/eye/brow expressions**. I don't think there is one. In fact, I submit, if you asked someone to draw a "scowl", you would get a whole array of pictures (eyes, brows, mouths, and teeth etc.) - all different. However, there are **verbs that vividly imply the "look" on ones face** - at least to those with active visual imaginations.

The "**facial**" expressions used by Puss in the Disney Shrek film are expressions of ***solicitation***. The **brow's upward inflection** is suggestive of having a "**begging**" posture (being of lowly/poor estate) or of "**humbly asking**" (request from a lower rank). *The facial expression also conveys **sincere need** (it's all in the eyes) in an attempt **to "solicit" pity or a merciful response**.*

Several descriptive **verbs** that **suggest** similar composites of **facial features** are:

> **to beg**, or **to beseech**, **to supplicate**, or **to plead**, **to entreat**, or **to implore**.
>
> **One example:** *The entire look on her face **implored** him to give in*.

[Begging TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/begging)

[Supplicating TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/supplicating)

[Pleading TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pleading)

[Beseech TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beseech)

[Entreat TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/entreat)

[Implore TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/implore)

Comment: Yup. they are verbs, and they really do conjure up facial images, but, no , the images are not only limited to the face.